# How can I SELECT multiple artboards To duplicate them in Adobe Illustrator with action or with script?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, illustrator-scripting, actions, javascript

I have like 270 files each file have 4 artboards, So I want to duplicate the ArtB(3) and ArtB(4) For 80 times, but I need a script to select the artboards that i need then duplicate them in action to let it work as a bath automatically, So can you help me pleas.[image]

Comment: Scripts have no way to select artboards! (Unless some new change has been made) So if you want to do this then you must do the duplication in the script. But this involves a lot of code.

Comment: Would it take maybe 10 seconds per document to do it manually? So around 45 minutes. The world's most boring video game, but doable. I'm just thinking if we knew *why* you want to do this, we might be able to come up with a workaround.

Comment: @Wolff can you watch this post there is a video in the comment where i explain what i want from this https://www.facebook.com/groups/adobeillustratortutorials/posts/1108910939940826/?__cft__[0]=AZUMV7swY4918HkGFk-jyHGtkC3yLJAWreY3of08CBQW4iAFXOpz_5OthxkWU_8qaj2K1MaV8CUHiNnvDT4prMFHCyrD2fmvoB1SE0CRoXgNxqH7IG9X_60Wgwsvv1ZdDVedLwaCLjMuDLAm94O6Me8X&__tn__=%2CO%2CP-R

Comment: OK I've watched your video. So you actually want 80 copies of the two art boards. Not just one copy. You should add this information to your question. It changes it a bit.

Comment: @Wolff ok bro thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

.. can't (or won't) log in to Facebook to see video.

**But**.. you **can** create new *rectangles* where you want them and then convert them to artboard easily.

Just draw rectangles at artboard edges.. select all and group. Make your copies.. then convert the copied rectangles to artboards. Duplicating 2 rectangular groups 80 times is easy.

To make selecting rectangles after creating copies faster, just add an off-color stroke to original before copying. You can then select all with a similar stroke and convert them artboards in one command.

---

I'd be remiss if I failed to mention, based upon the image in the question, **Indesign** would be better suited for this task, where *pages* are easily added/replicated.

Comment: woow thanks man it works but i find another problem that when i convert the rectangles to an artboard the order of this artboard it's not the same as their position, so there is in solution of that.

Comment: If order is important, I'd stress again that Indesign is a better tool. I don't think there's any shortcut to reordering artboards in Illustrator, other than the "rearrange" command. You'll probably just need to open the artboard panel and manually reorder things.

Comment: ok, thank you for your help i really appreciate it.

Comment: Order of artboards is order of objects in the object (layer) stack @SoBrawl so just reorder the objects before conversion

Comment: thanks @joojaa i tried to reorder the objects before starting the action and it works